# Certain components (made from three.js) is not rendering and loading on certain devices

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, gltf

I recenlty created my personal portfolio website using Three.js where I used certain gltf files and three.js components. After deploying the website I could easily access every component on my desktop, iphone 12 pro max, ipad pro but it's showing error for many android devices. I have attached the console errors of the android phones herewith.

Can somebody please help me with it?

My Portfolio link: [Sagnik Saha](https://sagniksaha.netlify.app/)
[image: Console error]

I just want my website to load on every other devices, and compatible to every devices.